# IsDeletedInterceptor in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am migrating an application from ASP.NET MVC 5 running on .NET 4.8 to ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

I have installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` in the new project. The old project uses Entity Framework 6. I have the following classes that do not recognize several EntityFramework 6 items:

InterceptorExtensions.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder;

namespace Project.Extensions.Interceptors
{
    public static class InterceptorExtensions
    {
        public static DbModificationClause UpdateIfMatch(this DbModificationClause clause, string property, DbExpression expression)
        {
            return clause.IsFor(property)
                ? DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(clause.Property(), expression)
                : clause;
        }

        private static bool IsFor(this DbModificationClause clause, string property)
        {
            return clause.HasPropertyExpression() && clause.Property().Property.Name == property;
        }

        private static DbPropertyExpression Property(this DbModificationClause clause)
        {
            if (clause.HasPropertyExpression())
            {
                var setClause = (DbSetClause)clause;

                return (DbPropertyExpression)setClause.Property;
            }

            throw new Exception("Clause does not contain property expression. Use HasPropertyExpression method to check if it has property expression.");
        }

        private static bool HasPropertyExpression(this DbModificationClause clause)
        {
            var setClause = clause as DbSetClause;

            return setClause?.Property is DbPropertyExpression;
        }
    }
}
```

IsDeletedInterceptor.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.Linq;
using Project.Models;

namespace Project.Extensions.Interceptors
{
    public class IsDeletedInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
    {
        private const string IsDeletedColumnName = "IsDeleted";

        public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace)
                return;

            var db = interceptionContext.DbContexts.FirstOrDefault() as BaseCustomDbContext;

            if (interceptionContext.Result is DbQueryCommandTree queryCommand && db?.FilterOutIsDeletedResults == true)
                interceptionContext.Result = HandleQueryCommand(queryCommand);

            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult is DbDeleteCommandTree deleteCommand)
                interceptionContext.Result = HandleDeleteCommand(deleteCommand);
        }

        private static DbCommandTree HandleDeleteCommand(DbDeleteCommandTree deleteCommand)
        {
            var table = (EntityType)deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.EdmType;

            if (table.Properties.All(ep => ep.Name != IsDeletedColumnName))
                return deleteCommand;

            var setClauses = new List<DbModificationClause>
            {
                DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.Variable(deleteCommand.Target.VariableName).Property(IsDeletedColumnName), DbExpression.FromBoolean(true))
            };

            return new DbUpdateCommandTree(deleteCommand.MetadataWorkspace, deleteCommand.DataSpace, deleteCommand.Target, deleteCommand.Predicate, setClauses.AsReadOnly(), null);
        }

        private static DbCommandTree HandleQueryCommand(DbQueryCommandTree queryCommand)
        {
            return new DbQueryCommandTree(queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace, queryCommand.DataSpace, queryCommand.Query.Accept(new IsDeletedQueryVisitor()));
        }

        private class IsDeletedQueryVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
        {
            public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
            {
                var table = (EntityType)expression.Target.ElementType;

                if (table.Properties.All(ep => ep.Name != IsDeletedColumnName))
                    return base.Visit(expression);

                var binding = expression.Bind();

                return binding.Filter(binding.VariableType.Variable(binding.VariableName).Property(IsDeletedColumnName).NotEqual(DbExpression.FromBoolean(true)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EntityFrameworkConfiguration.cs:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Project.Extensions.Interceptors
{
    public class EntityFrameworkConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public EntityFrameworkConfiguration()
        {
            AddInterceptor(new IsDeletedInterceptor());
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this interceptor is to filter out records that have flag IsDeleted = true.

What changes/nuget packages/references are needed to make this work in .NET 6.0?

Comment: Probably you need [Global Query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your interceptor in Startup? If not here is an example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<BaseCustomDbContext>(options => options
    .AddInterceptors(new IsDeletedInterceptor()));
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors

Comment: The main issue is that several items, such as DbModificationClause, DbSetClause, etc., are from Entity Framework 6.